# Merge tags [angular2-forms] and [angular4-forms] into [angular-forms]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Basicly its [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and its naming issues as always.
Angular is now at version 5.2, with v6 planned for april.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-forms
legacy tag with 2300+ questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4-forms
legacy tag with 280+ questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-forms
evergreen tag with 260+ questions

**Why potentially not** - Angular Forms API has been stable between v4 and v5, but for v2 - lots of obsolete questions could still exist, so maybe let them just stay ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-forms?sort=votes&pageSize=50
From 50 top questions 47 were asked in 2016, 1 in 2015 and two before April 2017.